# Как дополнить( изменить) строку ( элемент) html

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

Делаю опрос в sharepoint,  в одном из вопросов нужно добавить в подвопросы описание, но в строку подвопроса входит максимум 255 символов. Понял, что необходимо через скрипт изменить подвопрос, но как именно? через document.getlemenetbyid() не пойму какой там id может быть. Подскажите, пожалуйста. [image: на скрине изображены пример, код страницы и сам опрос]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там есть класс `ms-gridT1`

`document.querySelectorAll('.ms-gridT1')` вернет коллекцию всех найденных элементов с этим классом... [элемент0, элемент1, элемент2...]. Нужно посчитать, который этот по счету (счет начинается с нуля) и записать

```
<style> .weight-100 {font-weight: 100;} </style>

<script> 
var grid = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-gridT1');

grid[номер].innerHTML = `Основной жирный текст 
  <div class="weight-100">- Знание </div>
  <div class="weight-100">- Знание </div> 
  <div class="weight-100">- Знание </div> 
  <div class="weight-100">- Знание </div> 
  <div class="weight-100">- Знание </div>`;
</script>

(!) Обратные кавычки... ``
```

div и так переносит на новую строку, останется убрать жирный шрифт.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую

Comment: Подскажите, что могло пойти не так?)  выдает ошибку, что элемент не является функцией: EditForm.aspx?ID=59&FirstField=_x0421__x043f__x0435__x0446__x04:572 Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorALL is not a function
    at EditForm.aspx?ID=59&FirstField=_x0421__x043f__x0435__x0446__x04:572

Comment: @НикитаВаськин `All`, не `ALL` — querySelectorAll

Comment: поправил, но теперь выдает: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
    at EditForm.aspx?ID=68&FirstField=_x0421__x043f__x0435__x0446__x04:573

Comment: вот код: https://codepen.io/Evilinsider/pen/rNBzOxO

Comment: @НикитаВаськин Код-то правильный, вопрос в том - когда он должен сработать) Как минимум - поставить скрипт в самом конце страницы, чтобы сначала HTML догрузился, потом скрипт.

Comment: создал функцию и потом вызвал её после полной загрузки страницы и всё получилось! спасибо Вам)

Comment: Не подскажите, а можно ли как-нибудь достать этот элемент и поменять по названию? А то, я так понимаю, в опросе на другой страничке есть тоже элемент(вопрос) с тем же классом, и скрипт также меняет и его.

Comment: В общем через цикл сделал, спасибо! Очень помогли)